# Is a mailchimp newsletter with an entity view in the content area possible?

Tags: views, 8, emails

I am a newbie on emailing solutions and I have to design a newsletter system that allows the customer to create a newsletter with some content + the 3 most recent articles.

I guess it could be possible with simplenews, but mailchimp is a requirement. So I was wondering if anyone has already tried to add an entity of view type in the content part of a mailchimp newsletter like it is possible to add a node entity type. Or by using a module like [Insert view](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert_view) or by simply adding a little token like this one:

> [view:my_view=my_display]

The context of the project is D8, but a D7 solution might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So nope. But there is another way using simplenews and place the view in the template of the newsletter, and then use another smtp instead of Mailchimp, like Mailjet which now has a release on D8.